# Escaping javascript apostrophe / quotation for eval function, so it still works as a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

[Following js code in a jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/243ur/)

JS:

```
function myFunc(foo){
    $(foo).val("magic, it works!... NOT");    
}

var x = "myFunc('input[name=\\'testme\\']')";


eval (x);
```

HTML:

```
<input name="testme" type="text" />
```

Someone got a clue what I could do?

Comment: Well if you put it in a DOM ready and you escape your `'` like in your question, it work : http://jsfiddle.net/243ur/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give this way:

```
function myFunc(foo){
    $(foo).val("magic, it works!... NOT");    
}

var x = "(myFunc('input[name=\"testme\"]'))";

eval(x);
```

Combine them inside the `()`. But you need to also consider this. You need to give in **No Wrap (body)**.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/243ur/2/

Answer (score 0):

## [Don't use eval.](http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval/)

In your example, you are passing `eval` a constant string. This can be replaced with simply the contents of the string. That's all `eval` is actually doing, except using `eval` makes it impossible for JavaScript engines to optimise your code.

Your example can be replaced with:

```
function myFunc(foo){
    $(foo).val("magic, it works!... NOT");
}

myFunc('input[name=\'testme\']');
```

Comment: well right. The example is for simplicity. The "constant" string is full of php variables and "ifs".